# How to scrape page using simple htmldom and PHP?

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the data in `<div id listing-page-cart-inner>` and `<div id="description text">` and `<div id="tags">`, but i am finding it difficult to mine data.

Can anyone guide me? I am not able to fetch data though first div that I mentioned I am able to scrape, but other div I am not able to. When I loop through the second foreach it takes longer time.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://etsy.com/listing/107492702/');
//$val =  $html->find('div[id=listing-page-cart-inner]');


function scraping_etsy() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('https://etsy.com/listing/107492702/');

        foreach($html->find('div[id=listing-page-cart-inner]') as $article) 
    {
        // get title
        //$item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
        // get details
        $item['details'] = trim($article->find('span', 0)->plaintext);
        // get intro
        //$lists = $articles->find('div[id=item-overview]');

        $item['list1'] = trim($article->find('li',0)->plaintext);
        $item['list2'] = trim($article->find('li',1)->plaintext);
        $item['list3'] = trim($article->find('li',2)->plaintext);
        $item['list4'] = trim($article->find('li',3)->plaintext);
        $item['list5'] = trim($article->find('li',4)->plaintext);

        /*foreach($article->find('li') as $al){
            $item['lists'] =trim($al->find('li')->plaintext);

        }*/

        $ret[] = $item;

    }


    foreach($html->find('div[id=description]') as $content){
        var_dump($content->find('text'));
        // $item['content'] = trim($content->find('div[id=description]')->plaintext);
        // $ret[] = $item;
    }
    // clean up memory
  $html->clear();
   unset($html);

    return $ret ;
}
$ret = scraping_etsy();

var_dump($ret);

/*foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo $v['title'].'<br>';
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['details'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>Diggs: '.$v['diggs'].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}*/
?>
```

Comment: the second loop takes longer because this returns the whole SimpleHTMLDom object instead of the `text`

Comment: i did lot of research and i have posted instead of down voting can you guys help me out here my question is i want to mine data from https://www.etsy.com/in-en/listing/107492702/butterfly-mobile-baby-crib-mobiles-baby this url specifically contents in div[id=tags],div[id=listing-page-cart-inner]and div[id=description] , i don't understand why i am not able to fetch this data it would be great if you guys can guide me

Comment: when i echo plaintext i am not able to fetch any data

Comment: the first foreach loop actually works, i've tested it. i just don't know what you intend to do in the second foreach though

Comment: Hello ghost  etsy.com/in-en/listing/107492702/ in this url i have to mine three div first foreach is working fine i want to mine data in div[id=tags] and div[id=description] also when i write the code and execute it gives null output

Comment: What does the dump of $html returns (before clearing it)? Does it actually contains the div you're searching?

Comment: it does not contain any data in it outputs string = Null

Comment: Start by finding out why then ;)

Answer (score 1):

As for getting children of those divs, just remember that if found the parent element, always use `->find('<the selector here>', 0)` always use the index to actually point to that element.

```
$html = file_get_html('https://etsy.com/listing/107492702/');
// listings with description
$div = $html->find('div#listing-page-cart-inner', 0); // here index zero
$main_description = $div->find('h1', 0)->innertext;
echo $main_description . '<br/><br/>';

$div_item_overview = $div->find('div#item-overview ul.properties li');
foreach ($div_item_overview as $overview) {
    echo $overview->innertext . '<br/>';
}

// tags
$div_tag = $html->find('div#tags', 0); // here index zero pointing to that element
$tags = array();
foreach($div_tag->find('ul li') as $li) {
    $tags[] = $li->find('a', 0)->innertext;
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($tags, 1), '</pre>';

// description
$div_description = $html->find('div#description', 0)->plaintext; // here pointing to index zero
echo $div_description;
```

Comment: @user3470929 sure im glad this was able to help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start always is to use 3d-party library, i.e. [Symfony DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)

It usage as easy as

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!</p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    print $domElement->nodeName;
}
```

And you can use filters like

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```

Comment: i need guidance in my parser rather than new library